# Login page from asp.net is not accessible from Android App

Tags: asp.net

I've created a LoginPage to Authenticate Android Users but I keep getting an

IIS 7.0 Detailed Error - 401.1 - Unauthorized

In the folder of that aspx page I have a web.config set up as such to allow access

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="~/MobileApp/LoginMobile.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you simply <allow users="?"/> The question mark indicates anonymous users only. If you are already known then why would you need to log in again?

Comment: It seems to be trying to login? Here is some more of the error message

"This error occurs when either the username or password supplied to IIS is invalid, or when IIS cannot use the username and password to authenticate the user."

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search of your error returned this solution:

As a quick and dirty fix, grant the `IIS_IUSRS` group *Read/Execute* or *Modify* permissions to your web folder.

To fix this properly you should grant the Application Pool Identity for your site *Read/Execute* or *Modify* permissions to your application's web folder. To do this:

1. Open IIS Manager, navigate to your website or application folder where the site is deployed to.
2. Open Advanced Settings (it's on the right hand *Actions* pane).
3. Note down the *Application Pool* name then close this window
4. Double click on the *Authentication* icon to open the authentication settings
5. Disable *Windows Authentication*
6. Right click on *Anonymous Authentication* and click `Edit`
7. Choose the `Application pool identity` radio button the click `OK`
8. Select the Application Pools node from IIS manager tree on left and select the Application Pool name you noted down in step 3
9. Right click and select *Advanced Settings*
10. Expand the Process Model settings and choose `ApplicationPoolIdentity` from the *"Built-in account"* drop down list then click `OK`.
11. Click `OK` again to save and dismiss the Application Pool advanced settings page
12. Open an Administrator command line (right click on the CMD icon and select "Run As Administrator". It'll be somewhere on your start menu, probably under Accessories.
13. Run the following command:

`icacls <path_to_site> /grant "IIS APPPOOL\<app_pool_name>"(CI)(OI)(M)`

For example:

`icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\ /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DEFAULTAPPPOOL":(CI)(OI)(M)`

If all is good `icacls.exe` will report:

```
processed file: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: This is a hosted environment so unfortunatley I don't think I could run those commands

Answer (score 0):

There was another connection being opened before making this call and was somehow interfering with it.